# How to fetch query results into a list?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to fetch the results of my Datastore query to a list in python. Then, I tried something like:

```
foo = db.GqlQuery("SELECT url FROM Ads").run()
```

and

```
foo = db.GqlQuery("SELECT url FROM Ads").fetch(10)
```

But both without luck - foo is just empty. How can I correctly fetch the results?\

**EDIT:** OK, I managed to make it work by using:

```
someList = []
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT url FROM Ads")

for p in q.run(limit=None, batch_size=1000):
    someList.append(p.url)
```

Is there some shorter solution to this?

Comment: If you really need a list you could use fetch.  If you are not going to re-use the list, I would look consider why you need a list and can't just iterate.  Oh and list(q.run(limit=None, batch_size=1000)) is easier than your for loop.

Comment: Note this comment about fetch in the docs  Note: This method is merely a thin wrapper around the run() method, and is less efficient and more memory-intensive than using run() directly. You should rarely need to use fetch(); it is provided mainly for convenience in cases where you need to retrieve a full in-memory list of query results.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying fields in a GQL statement (rather then `*`), you are actually running a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries). If you check your `index.yaml` file, you should see that the dev server has auto generated an index to support this query.

Typically, you would query for the entire entity, then iterate over the entities as required (in your case to build a list), just like you have done.

Projection queries may be useful if you have large entities, but frequently just need to query for a few specific properties, which would reduce latency / reduce bandwidth etc.